# Initialize Array in an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array, organization

With my Tile Editor that I created I get an Array like this:

```
int [][] Level02 = new int[][]  {
                            { 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 12}, 
                            { 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 12}, 
                            { 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, 13, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 13, -1, -1, 13, -1, -1, -1, -1, 12}, 
                            { 11, 13, -1, -1, 27, 27, 27, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 13, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 13, 13, -1, -1, -1, 13, 13, -1, -1, -1, 32, -1, -1, 27, 27, 25, 25, 27, 27, -1, -1, 32, 12}, 
                            { 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, -1, -1, 13, 13, -1, -1, -1, 13, -1, -1, -1, 25, 25, 25, -1, -1, -1, 27, 27, 27, 27, -1, -1, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16}, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
                        }
```

So it prints out a 2 dimensional array.

The problem is that I have hundreds of these in one class and what to organize them to be able to do like: `Levels.getlevelCount;`

So I figured out that I could do a 3 dimensional Array: `int [][][] AllLevels = new int [][][]`

But my question is:
Are there anyway to declare an array within another sort of like this:

```
int[][][] all = new int[][][]{


      int [][] Level01= new int[][] {
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}};

int [][] Level02= new int[][] {
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}};


        };
```

Above code gives a Compiling Error.

Comment: If you have this kind of arrays, consider removing the data from the code and initializing the arrays from file/db. The people that will have to mantain your code will thank you.

Comment: I dont have any files. My tile editor gives me this. And I dont see how like my graphic designer will care :D

Comment: You already got the answer, I'd just like to point you to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html Java Naming Conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you have there but you can do this.

```
int [][] twod1 = {{1, 1,}, {-1, -1}};

int [][] twod2 = {{1, 1,}, {-1, -1}};

int [][][] threed = {twod1, twod2};
```

Or you can do it in reverse if you prefer.

```
int [][][] threed2 = {{{1, 1,}, {-1, -1}},
                     {{1, 1,}, {-1, -1}}};

int [][] twod3 = threed2[0];

int [][] twod4 = threed2[1];
```

You can also do it inline, I don't think its very readable though. If you do it inline you also can't use short hand initialization you actually have to declare the `new int[][]` for each 2-dimensional int array.

```
int [][] twod5; 

int [][] twod6;

int [][][] threed3 = { twod5 = new int[][]{{1, 1,}, {-1, -1}},
                       twod6 = new int[][]{ {1, 1,}, {-1, -1}}};
```

Comment: Great! But are they're anyone to replace the {twod1, twod2}; with actually initialize?

Comment: @AndroidXtr3meN I updated my answer with the reverse scenario is that closer to what you need?

Comment: This all compiles so you should be able to copy/paste these segments if you need.

Comment: Thank you, but

int [][][] threed3 = { 
      int [][] array2d= new int[][]{{1, 1,}, {-1, -1}};
      
               };

didnt work somehow

Comment: change it to  `int [][] array2d; int [][][] threed3 = { array2d= new int[][]{{1, 1,}, {-1, -1}} };` You cannot declare an array inside another array, only assign it.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[][][] all = .....

int[][] level1 = all[0];
int[][] level2 = all[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, here's a 2D example:

```
int[] level1, level2;
int[][] all = new int[][] {
    level1 = new int[]{ 1, 2 },
    level2 = new int[]{ 3, 4 }
 };
```

So first we declare the variables for each level `level1` and `level2`. I'm assuming you want references to them judging from your example. If not, then you can leave them out. So a multi-dimensional array is just an array of arrays of arrays... So you can simply initialize each element of the top-level array separately.

Then notice that the assignment operator `=` actually returns a value, the value of the assignment.

Comment: Well I meant Declare a 2 Dimensional array in a 3rd. Another word one step more than you show

Comment: The idea is the same. I just did a 2D example to illustrate the concept used.

Comment: You need to declare level1 and level2 separately, as in tskuzzy's example, and then assign them in the declaration of all -- if you want to use this approach.

Comment: @AndroidXTr3meN: Declare `Level01` and `Level02` outside of the first array. Then leave out the `int[][]` declarations in the array initializer.

Comment: But if i have lets say 30 arrays then i have to do like int [][][] = and all the arrays...takes forever

Comment: @tskuzzy there must be a way to do it inside?

Comment: If you have 30 arrays, then why don't you just use all[i] instead of creating 30 variables?